# Amazon s3 unable to fetch images even though its public

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, php-curl

I have OVH VPS and I'm using PHP CURL to fetch images. But it's showing some errors,

```
[Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException]
  Error: Error getting remote image http://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/productimages1234/images/elegantayeshav5-01.jpg Error: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 9775 milliseconds with 440188 out
  of 3573589 bytes received. [woocommerce_api_invalid_remote_product_image]
```

I have made bucket public and it's folder public and also images but getting this error.

I can open this image on browser and I can do wget on vps but it's not working with CURL.

Link : http://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/productimages1234/images/elegantayeshav5-01.jpg

Thank you !

Comment: Looks like a connection problem instead of a permission problem because of the timeout error.

Comment: I have tried to check the image. I think, image is too big in size. Image does not download completely even after 3 minutes in browser. You should check Timeout settings. You can increase timeout value and check to make sure that it is the problem.

Comment: Which timeout should I increase ?